# How can join three diferents tables where a column is the sum for each component?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a three tables:

> geo(geo_id, geo_city, \ldots)
>   person(person_id, geo_id, \ldots)
>   ticket(person_id, numbertickes,\ldots)

How can I form a table where the columns are geo_city and visit, where visit is the sum of number of tickets on each city.

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` AS A
INNER JOIN `geo` AS B ON B.geo_id = A.geo_id
INNER JOIN `ticket` AS C ON C.CLI_ID = A.CLI_ID
WHERE B.geo_id IS NOT NULL
AND C.person_id IS NOT NULL;
```

I need a column with the sum group by city, something `SUM(numbertickes)`

Comment: Is `mytable` supposed to be `person`?

Comment: Use `SUM(numbertickets)` and `GROUP BY geo_city`.

Comment: That's exactly what you said in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Join the 3 tables, and select the city and `SUM(numbertickets)`.

```
SELECT g.geo_city, SUM(t.numbertickets) AS visits
FROM geo AS g
JOIN person AS p ON p.geo_id = g.geo_id
JOIN ticket AS t ON t.person_id = p.person_id
GROUP BY g.geo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT g.geo_city, SUM(t.numbertickets) visit FROM ticket t
  JOIN person p USING(person_id)
  JOIN geo g USING(geo_id)
  WHERE g.geo_id IS NOT NULL && p.person_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY g.geo_city ORDER BY t.numbertickets DESC
```

Of course, I'm assuming you spelled numbertickets correctly. Shows numbertickes in your post.